# selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException using Selenium in python 3.7

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, python-3.7, xpath-1.0

I want to use selenium to automate the process from open a specific website to log in to search for particular articles. Few of the steps I could do it but facing error in 'sign in' step.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
base = 'https://www.wsj.com'
url = 'https://www.wsj.com/search/term.html?KEYWORDS=cybersecurity&min-date=2018/04/01&max-date=2019/03/31&isAdvanced=true&daysback=90d&andor=AND&sort=date-desc&source=wsjarticle,wsjpro&page=1'

browser = webdriver.Safari(executable_path='/usr/bin/safaridriver')
browser.get(url)
browser.find_element_by_id('editions-select').click()
browser.find_element_by_id('na,us').click()
browser.find_element(By.XPATH, '//button[@type="button"],[contain(.,"Sign In")]').click()
browser.find_element_by_id('username').send_keys('**#&^&@$@#$')
browser.find_element_by_id('password').send_keys('@#@$%%**')
browser.find_element_by_id('basic-login').click()
browser.find_element_by_id('masthead-container').click()
browser.find_element_by_id('searchInput').send_keys('cybersecurity')
browser.find_element_by_name('ADVANCED SEARCH').click()
browser.find_element_by_id('dp1560924131783').send_keys('2018/04/01')
browser.find_element_by_id('dp1560924131784').send_keys('2019/03/31')
browser.find_element_by_id('wsjblogs').click()
browser.find_element_by_id('wsjvideo').click()
browser.find_element_by_id('interactivemedia').click()
browser.find_element_by_id('sitesearch').click()
```

The code is working till this line:

```
browser.find_element_by_id('na,us').click()
```

But after that it is showing error in this line:

```
browser.find_element(By.XPATH, '//button[@type="button"],[contain(.,"Sign In")]').click()
```

The error message says​:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message:
```

What is wrong is my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error message...

```
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException
```

...implies that the *XPath* expression was not a valid one.

However, it seems you were close. You need to replace:

```
'//button[@type="button"],[contain(.,"Sign In")]'
```

and join the two condition with *`and`* operator as follows:

```
"//button[@type='button' and contains(.,'Sign In')]"
```

Comment: Not working. The same line is giving an error but this time the error is different selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException

Comment: @PiyushGhasiya `NoSuchElementException` is a different error all together where as your current issue was `InvalidSelectorException`. Feel free to raise a new question as per your new requirement. StackOverflow volunteers will be happy to help you out.